# Are there any lightweight travel alarm clocks?

Tags: luggage, electronic-items, sleeping

I am looking for a lightweight, portable alarm clock for travel? This is my feature list:

- Preferably analogue display, with florescent hands.
- No ticking noise!
- Alarm *with snooze*.
- Alarm does not stop beeping after N minutes or X snooze cycles.
- Lightweight and compact for storage, and the alarm can be disabled so it won't beep in the bag.

Something along the lines of the [Casio TQ-140](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Casio-TQ140-Mini-Beep-Analogue-Bedside-Alarm-Clock-Black-/400915900120?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item5d587326d8) would be great, but I'm not sure if it ticks and *it has no snooze*. I would use the alarm on my phone, but it is [known](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113388/alarm-silent-even-when-not-in-silent-mode?noredirect=1#comment140200_113388) to be [buggy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14724/how-to-make-my-alarm-as-stable-as-a-server?rq=1).

Comment: Relevant question, but posed as an opinion poll, please reformat. Close voting as opinion-based.

Comment: My iPhone alarm has served me well in many countries since I bought it. Before that I used Android without difficulty. There might be reasons to use a different alarm clock but I think "buggy" is not really one of them. Fix the bug instead!

Comment: @GayotFow: Thank you, I've reformated the question slightly to not give the appearance of a poll. The format is bassed on [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31397/good-gps-device-to-tracking-my-travels?rq=1).

Comment: @dotancohen, still borderline, but nobody else has closed voted, so you might be good.

Comment: Three close votes so far. I've tried to remove the opinion-basedness from the question title and body.

Comment: Previously I've used those types of analog travel alarms even at home. The analog ones always had an audible tick. To keep them going off in a bag, I just pulled the battery. Now, I'm using my android phone's clock alarm.

Comment: @JoErNanO: Thank you. The close votes are before the edit, should I mention this on meta? I've linked to [another upvoted question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31397/good-gps-device-to-tracking-my-travels?rq=1) which fits the same format, which demonstrates that this question is in the appropriate format for the site.

Comment: A search term may be "silent sweep hand"

Comment: @dotancohen Worst case scenario we can always vote to reopen. ;)

Comment: @mkennedy: Thank you, that key phrase was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [mkennedy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/465/mkennedy)'s comment on the question, I found [this clock](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Seiko-QHE118S-Silver-Analogue-Luminous-Snooze-Silent-Sweep-Beep-Alarm-Clock-New-/271825336554?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item3f4a0d78ea) on Ebay and [others](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Black-Silver-Alarm-Clock-Silent-Sweep-No-Ticking-Snooze-Plus-Light-/400892041146?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item5d570717ba) [like](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Small-Alarm-Clock-Light-Snooze-Sweep-Silent-Movement-Various-Colours-/281618229678?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item4191c129ae) [it](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Acctim-Sensa-Light-Non-Ticking-Sweep-Seconds-Hand-Alarm-Clock-with-Snooze-14677-/291422287790?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item43da1f37ae). The key phrase, as mentioned in her comment, is:

> silent sweep hand

Combining that key phrase with `snooze` led to many options. Unfortunately, I have no way of checking if any of the alarms do not stop beeping after N minutes or X snooze cycles before purchase. If I find such a clock then I'll update this answer and accept it. In the meantime, I hope that this hint helps other travelers with their clocks!

[image: clock]